# DotRas Library for VS expres for windows phone

Tags: c#, dll, windows-phone, ras

I'm working with c# at the moment and I'm making an application that makes a connection to a vpn. I downloaded the DotRas to do so, however the library's included doesn't support Visual Studio Express for windows phone. Does anyone has an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Check [OpenNetCF Ras Library](http://rascf.codeplex.com/) Library. It can be used for Compact Framework and WinCE Devices. I am not sure whether it will work with Windows Phone Development. I just wanted to suggest to have a look.